# Does aws amplify work with NextJS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, next.js, aws-amplify

I am just trying to get a basic hello world running with NextJS and aws-amplify but it seems the moment I npm install the two libraries

aws-amplify & aws-amplify-react

I get 'react module missing' & window is not defined.

```
import React from 'react'
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';

Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
        // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Identity Pool ID
        identityPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-1234-abcd-1234567890ab',
        // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Region
        region: 'XX-XXXX-X',
        // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
        userPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X_abcd1234',
        // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Web Client ID
        userPoolWebClientId: 'XX-XXXX-X_abcd1234',
    }
});

export default class extends React.Component {
    static async getInitialProps({ req }) {
        const userAgent = req ? req.headers['user-agent'] : navigator.userAgent
        return { userAgent }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              Hello World
              <style jsx>{`

            `}</style>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make some kind of polyfill to avoid that `window is not defined` error. Also maybe you need to check your `node_modules` folder to see if `react` is correctly installed.

The polyfill example:
```

```
(<any>global).window = (<any>global).window || {};
(<any>global).localStorage = (<any>global).localStorage || {
    store: {},
    getItem(key){
        if (this.store[key]) {
            return this.store[key];
        }
        return null;
    },
    setItem(key, value){
        this.store[key] = value;
    },
    removeItem(key){ delete this.store[key]; }
};
```

```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Install tslib and then test

npm install tslib

Comment: To make this answer more useful to readers of this question, consider adding a description to explain what you're doing and why your doing it.